# Which one is the correct phrase?

Tags: third-person-singular

What's the correct way of saying the following phrase:

> How fast this beast go?

or

> How fast this beast goes?

The thing here is that I know the object that we are talking about is "beast" and therefore the verb should be goes (third person) but it kind of sounds weird if I use it.

Comment: You should look at how to form questions in English, like at https://www.espressoenglish.net/an-easy-way-to-form-almost-any-question-in-english/ and https://www.fluentu.com/blog/english/wh-questions/

Answer (score 2):

The correct way should be:

> How fast does this beast go?

After using do / does, the [main verb should be in its base form](https://learnersdictionary.com/qa/did-main-verb-base-form-or-past-tense-form).